# Jquery change/set link params on click

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, onclick

I need to click a link by jquery dynamically.

And before click, I set some extra or new params to that link.

```
      $('#add-new-event a:first').attr('href', `/admin/content/events/add/lesson?popup=/day-view&start=2019-10-15T08:00:00&end=2019-10-15T08:15:00&instructor=673`);
      $('#add-new-event a:first').click();
      console.log($('#add-new-event a:first').attr('href'));
```

It set params correctly, but the params that sent are not updated and it gets the old params. How it is possible to add new or extra params to a link when it is clicked by jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.link').click(function(e){
    this.href='/admin/content/events/add/lesson?popup=/day-view&start=2019-10-15T08:00:00&end=2019-10-15T08:15:00&instructor=673';
    console.log(this.href);
    //use e.preventDefault() to prevent redirect to check updation
  });
  $('.link')[0].click();    // call click()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://foo.bar" class='link'>click me!</a>
```

Comment: I want to click link dynamically!

Comment: @Nasser you just have to call click on the underlying element. I have updated the code anyhow.

Comment: your answer is working, but in my case still, I can't get the link prams.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `click` event does not work on anchor tags. You will have to updated your code as below

```
      $('#add-new-event a:first').attr('href', `/admin/content/events/add/lesson?popup=/day-view&start=2019-10-15T08:00:00&end=2019-10-15T08:15:00&instructor=673`);
      $('#add-new-event a:first').get(0).click();
      console.log($('#add-new-event a:first').attr('href'));
```

I am assuming that your HTML is something like below:

```
       <div id="add-new-event">
        <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
       </div>
```

This will change the href value of your anchor tag and call the click event. Don't forget the `target="_blank"` property if you want to check the console.

Here is the Demo at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8hkae1cx/)

Comment: your answer is working, but in my case still, I can't get the link prams.